# Package dependency error message when install octave on RedHat linux

Tags: installation, redhat-enterprise-linux, octave

Hi I tried to install octave on my RedHat 5 Linux. I typed command as

```
yum install octave
```

Then, it complained as following :

```
gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-44.el5.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgfortran = 4.1.2-44.el5 is needed by package gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-44.el5.x86_64 (installed)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgfortran = 4.1.2-44.el5 is needed by package gcc-gfortran-4.1.2-44.el5.x86_64 (installed)
```

However, when I typed command as

```
yum list libgfortran
```

It did show something as

```
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security  
Installed Packages  
libgfortran.x86_64               4.1.2-44.el5               installed             
Available Packages  
libgfortran.i386                 4.1.2-52.el5               rhel-x86_64-client-5  
libgfortran.x86_64               4.1.2-52.el5               rhel-x86_64-client-5
```

Doesn't it mean I have libgfortran 4.1.2-44.e15 installed already ? Why does it still complain ? Does anyone have any idea how this can be solved ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

libgfortran = 4.1.2-44.el5 you have installed is probably 32bit version. Try install the 64bit version and that should resolve the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found out my epel package is i386 version so I also installed the 32 bit version of libgfortran 32 versions. And it works now.